# how to handle a space in the path attribute of a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, path, fetch

I have the following html and php files:

a.html

```
async function fun()
{
x=await fetch('/about me/a.php');
x=await x.text();
alert(x);
}
fun();
```

a.php

```
setcookie('usercookie','a value',['path'=>'/about me/']);
echo 'hello';
```

When I remove the space in the path attribute, it works fine; otherwise, I cannot see the cookie. How do you handle spaces in the path attribute of a cookie?

Many Thanks for help

Comment: Properly URL-encode the path …?

Comment: I used urlencode() function but I still cannot get the cookie. on the other hand, If I used urlencode() on a path that has no spaces, I cannot get the cookie.

Comment: As you recommended, I encoded the path using PHP's urlencode() function, but the path in the fetch() URL parameter doesn't need to be encoded, does it?

Comment: It _should_ be. The browser will handle that automatically for you, if you fail to do it, but that is not a good reason to neglect proper handling of such issues to begin with. And why do you even have a space in such an URL in the first place? That is a rather bad idea to begin with. If you need to separate “words” in readable URLs, then use a minus or an underscore.

Comment: Is the PHP's urlencode() the right function to use?